# Python what does while set variable do?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a set and I do while set: like the following, when does the loop stop?

```
x={'3', '4', '2'}
while x:
    print(1)
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: while `x` evaluates to `True` (i.e. `x` is not an empty set `{}`) `print(1)`. If `x` never changes this is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

`while` over *any* non-empty variable will never stop if you never modify that variable within the while body.

Answer (score 0):

Never.

Because `while` evaluates the truthiness of x, which is True - and so you have an infinite loop.

You can try it yourself with [`bool(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) or have a look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth

Answer (score 0):

to understand what your code is doing you need to understand how a while statement works.

The `while` statement is a Boolean statement.

What this means is `(True,False)`

for example:

```
x = True
while x: # without saying true or false here "while" assumes you are checking for true.
    print ("X is True")
    x = False
```

The above code will run the commands inside of it until `x == False`.
So the code will run one time because I have said `x = False` at the end of the statement.

the above code is the same as saying.

```
x = True
while x is True:
    print ("X is True")
    x = False
```

In your example:

```
x={'3', '4', '2'}
while x:
    print(1)
```

`x` will always be `True` if you do not change it to be False or something that is equal to False.
Therefore your loop will never end "MUAHAHAHAHAHAHHA"

For example:

```
x = True
while x:
    print (1)
    x = 0
```

Or:

```
x = 12
while x:
    print (1)
    x = 0
```

This will print out the number `1` only one time because x has been assigned `0` and is the equivalent of False for the while statement.